# ubuntu seems to refuse to connect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to connect to my home WiFi and it will not connect to any access point in the house. My only internet on my computer is my phone tethered to the computer or I log into windows. My WiFi Adapters run Fine in windows but can only see available networks in Linux. I only get errors when connecting to the access points in the house. Under Windows I have no issues with the 2 WiFi adapters.

some info on the OS and adapters

- Linux: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Windows: Win10 1902
- WiFi adapter 1: Alfa AWUS1900 (rtl8814AU) [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MZD7Z76) [Driver Github](https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU)
- WiFi adapter 2: Blueshadow USB WiFi adapter(8812BU) [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0791YX15L) [Driver Github](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_26334.20180126_COEX20171012-5044)

lsusb

```
    termanater13@Term-Linux:~$ lsusb
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b1c:1b34 Corsair 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:0169 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)
    Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:8813 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lshw (was getting error about inaccurate or incomplete and to run as root hence sudo)

```
    termanater13@Term-Linux:~$ sudo lshw -C network
      *-network                 
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:18:00.0
           logical name: enp24s0
           version: 15
           serial: 00:d8:61:53:9b:28
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
           resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
      *-network:0
           description: Wireless interface
           physical id: 1
           bus info: usb@1:2
           logical name: wlx00c0caa6d428
           serial: 00:c0:ca:a6:d4:28
           capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8814au multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
      *-network:1
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 2
           logical name: enp21s0f0u6
           serial: 92:02:16:8a:d3:d4
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.144 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Note: My WiFi finally connected then about one minute later shows no signal so no connection. currently using my phone as my WiFi adapter till I can get it fixed.

Comment: What have you tried to configure them, and what was the result? What happens when you boot with a LiveUSB and try to connect then? What do you get when you run _lsusb_ and _lshw -C network_? Please click [edit] and enhance your original post with that highly useful information. Please do not click [Add Comment] because comments get pushed off the screen by newer comments.